# Problems in suggesting text in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

So i got this message when I tried to run my project: 'Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.', so I changed the compileSdk in gradle file to 33, so heres how it looks now:

android {
compileSdk 33

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kotlinvjezbanje2"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

and now my project is running correctly, but now I don't get suggestions while typing in xml, anyone knows the reason why?

When I change the compileSdk to 32 I can't run the app but I get code suggestions